# URL rewriting for nested level directories

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a assets folder in my webserver which contain files like javascript, css and deep level of other folders. When user tries to access this folder using url like:

```
www.example.com/assets
```

I show then 404.html file, which is done easily as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/assets/$ /404.html [NC,L]
```

But as I say it a multiple folder inside it, also for which show 404 error. I don't want to write rewrite rule for all the folders inside it (because their is many). I am a beginner in url rewriting, can anybody show me how can I achieve this with a line or two lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line:

```
RewriteRule ^/assets/(([^/]*)/)+$ /404.html
```

Which will match /assets/{anything}/{anything}/{anything}/...

Comment: it will match with /assets/{anything}/ but not /assets/{anything}/{anything}/{anything}.. I mean their are multi-level directories and I want user to access on any of those until its a file

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to prevent visitors from listing the files in your directories, you can use

```
Options -Indexes
```

in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: yes, it is, but I thought it was relevant to what the OP might be trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You just need this rule to forward all `/assets/*` requests to /404.html:

```
RewriteRule ^assets(/|$) /404.html [NC,L]
```

Make sure this rule is your first rule.